# How to model these relashionships?

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Well, these are two simple entities but with many interactions which makes me a bit confused about how to do the relationship setup ..

So, I have two entities .. Category and Article .. It seems simple.. but here are what I need to do:

- Categories can be a standalone model with no relationships
- Category can contain other categories
- Categories can contain Articles
- Articles can be standalone (not inside categories)

How do you think I can model these entities and relationships between them?

Comment: My best guess would be that Category has hasMany relationships on both Categories and Articles (and in the same way a belongsTo relation which can be null). The foreign keys could still be null, thus being a "standalone" category or article.

Answer (score 1):

Most straightforward:

```
// categories table: category_id fk categories.id nullable

// Category model
public function parent()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category', 'category_id');
}

public function children()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Category', 'category_id');
}

public function articles()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Article');
}
```

---

```
// articles table: category_id fk categories.id nullable

// Article model
public function category()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('Category');
}
```

Mind that if you wish to build a tree of those categories and then load whole tree, this will not be easy. If that's the case you should use eg. `adjacency list` or other model for self-referencing tables.